# Continuous Deployment using Jenkins and Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-deployment

We are building a java based high-availability service for a financial application. I am part of the team for managing continuous integration using Jenkins.

Lately we introduced continuous deployment too in the list and we opted for Docker containers.

Here is the the infrastructure:

The production cluster will have 3 RHEL machines running the following docker containers on each of them:

- 3 instances of Wildfly
- Cassandra
- Nginx

Application IDE is Netbeans and source code is in git.

Currently we are doing manual deployment on this infrastructure.

Please suggest me some tools which I use with Jenkins to complete the continuous deployment process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You might want jenkins to trigger on each push to your jenkins repository. There are plugins that help you do that with a webhook.[Gitlab-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin) is a solution similar solution exist for Github and other git solutions.
- Instead of heavily relying on bash and jenkins configuration you might want to setup a [jenkins pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) with the jenkins pipeline plugin or even [pipeline: multibranch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin). With those you can automate your build in groovy code (jenkinsfile) in a repository with the possibility to add functunality with other plugins building on them.
- You can then use the docker pipeline plugin to easily build docker containers, push docker images and run code inside docker containers.
- I would suggest building your services inside docker so that your jenkins machine does not have all the different dependencies installed (and therefore maybe conflicting versions). Use docker containers with all the dependencies and run your build code in there with the docker pipeline plugin from groovy.
- Install a registry solution to push and pull your docker images to.
- Use the [Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin) to extract libraries from your jenkinsfiles so that they can be reused. Those library files should have their own repository which your jenkins knows about and keeps up to date. Possibly you can even have an entire pipeline process shared between multiple projects which simply add parameters in their jenkinsfile.

A lot of text and no examples. If you think something is interesting and you want to see some code just ask. I am currently setting all this up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply herm. My understanding is to run pipeline, I need to make target machines as jenkins nodes. Is this correct? Do i need to install Docker on Jenkins master?

Comment: It will be very helpful herm if you can guide us. Most of the time i face issues because of running behind corporate proxy. I would be very interested to see how the setup will work and would like to contribute too

Comment: Any jenkins machine on which you want to execute docker commands would require docker to be installed. The target machines should not have anything to do with jenkins. You could SSH to from jenkins pull your newly built image and run a docker container.